# JLabel positioning is not working

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager

I need to position the `JLabel` in my `JFrame`. I created a label and wanted to set its position, but both `setAlignment` and `setBounds` do not work. The label stays all the time at the top of the panel and it does not move.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Start extends JFrame {
    //JLabel label1 = new JLabel("HELLO!");
    //JLabel label2 = new JLabel("CHOOSE LANGUAGE:");

    public Start() {
        super();
        setSize(480, 360);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        //setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

        add(panel1);
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("HELLO!");
        //label1.setBounds(20,20,100,20);
        //label1.SetAlignmentX(20);
        //label1.SetAlignmentY(20);
        panel1.add(label1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Start frame = new Start();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Could you help?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. "not working" isn't a working problem description.

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. There are different ways to influence the layout. Maybe you can use a GridBagLayout. By default the component will be centered in the frame. Or maybe a BoxLayout. `The label stays all the time at the top of the panel and it does not move.` We don't know what "move" means.  If you want the component 20 pixels from the top then maybe you can use  a Border on the label. Without a proper requirement we can't give a specific suggestion.

Comment: Read the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are section on `Using Layout Managers` and `How to Use Borders` to help you effectively position components.

Comment: I'll repeat my previous answer as a comment: You have to do `panel1.setLayout(null)` before the explicit positioning of the JLabel will have any effect. Yes, explicit positioning may not be the way Swing usually works, but it's not forbidden either. Now I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the intended layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. This is the best I can guess the requirement from the current description.

It shows how to pad the left and top of the label (by using an `EmptyBorder`) by 20 pixels in the red panel, and by 100 x 30 in the blue panel.

[image]

Read the comments in the code for further tips, and check the Java Docs for any methods used that are different to the original source code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Start extends JFrame {

    public Start() {
        super();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(SwingConstants.LEADING));
        panel1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED, 4));
        add(panel1);
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("HELLO!", SwingConstants.LEADING);
        //label1.setBounds(20,20,100,20);

        // to provide a 20 x 20 offset, an empty border will do nicely.
        label1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 0, 0));

        // Did you actually check the Java Docs for these methods? 
        // They do not do what you seem to think they do.
        //label1.SetAlignmentX(20);
        //label1.SetAlignmentY(20);
        panel1.add(label1);

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(SwingConstants.LEADING));
        panel2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE, 4));
        add(panel2);
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("HELLO!", SwingConstants.LEADING);
        label2.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(30, 100, 30, 100));
        panel2.add(label2);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Start frame = new Start();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```